# recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) When no Internet access

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app for android only form ice cream sandwich to jelly bean android versions.

I have a function that detects if there is a Internet connection, that works great.

But when the device has connection but no Internet access it crash and send me the follow excpetion

```
HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

For example, when the divice has the 3G data on but not Internet access because it doesnt have any balance for data.

I am using [http-request library](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) to make the request to the server.

I also try to catch the exception to handle the error and bring user feedback but Eclipse send me an error

```
this exception is never thrown for the try statement body
```

This is my first try

```
    if(LaConstante.isConected(ctx)){
        try{
            new ObtenerTiposReporte().execute(b.getString("tipo"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            if (e.getMessage().indexOf("Connection reset by peer") > 0);
        }
    }else{
        ProgressBar progressBarListaReportes = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarListaReportes);
        progressBarListaReportes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Lo sentimos, se requiere de una conexión a Internet para reportar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i2 = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i2);
    }
```

I also try directly catch the exception when the request was made

```
        String jsonString = "";

        try{
            jsonString = HttpRequest.post(LaConstante.getInstance().TIPOS_DE_REPORTE+params[0]).form(data).body();
        }catch(IOException e){
            if (e.getMessage().indexOf("Connection reset by peer") > 0);
        }
```

I dont know how to handle the error to bring feedback to the user that whats in happening.

Comment: Your line from the log makes it look as if this Exception is being **caught** and interpreted *within* the HttpRequest class, rather than **thrown** back up the call stack by it.  If that's the case, then Eclipse is indeed correct, and you'll need to find some other way to determine that this has occurred.